# How to touch from button1 to button2 , the highlighted will be change?

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I wanna make two button, A and B.

When I tap buttonA , buttonA state is highlight.

I drag my finger from ButtonA to buttonB, I wanna buttonA.state is not highlighted, buttonB.state is highlighted.

but it doesn't work...

When I drag to buttonB, the buttonA.state still highlighted,and buttonB.state is not highlighted.

I need help. Thanks

Comment: please put your code that you tried

Comment: show your code , whether we know what the mistake u did

Comment: That's not how `UIButton`s work. You'd have to write a custom control.

Comment: I drag buttonA and buttonB to under  @interface. There are two IBOutlet of buttonA and buttonB. what should I add in the IBOutlet?